# bokeh hbar example with categorical values = white box

Tags: python, bokeh

I've got code for a simple hbar plot that is stripped down to what I think should be, but shows up as a white box.  (I can get the simple example of a line plot working so I know the headers are set up correctly.)

```
        from bokeh.embed import components
        from bokeh.plotting import figure

        fruits = ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Nectarines', 'Plums', 'Grapes', 'Strawberries']
        counts = [5, 3, 4, 2, 4, 6]

        p = figure(plot_height=250, title="Fruit counts",
                   toolbar_location=None, tools="")

        p.hbar(y=fruits, right=counts)

        data, div = components(p)
```

The error in the console is "[Bokeh] could not set initial ranges"
If someone could point me to the documentation about anything needing to be added that would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are [working with categorical data](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html), you need to assign a `FactorRange` for your `y_range`. This is done either by `p.y_range=FactorRange(factors=fruits)` or its shorthand version `p.x_range=fruits`.
The following example shows the figure corectly:

```
from bokeh.embed import components
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import FactorRange

fruits = ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Nectarines', 'Plums', 'Grapes', 'Strawberries']
counts = [5, 3, 4, 2, 4, 6]

p = figure(y_range=FactorRange(factors=fruits), plot_height=250, title="Fruit counts",
            toolbar_location=None, tools="")

p.hbar(y=fruits, right=counts)

show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Just FYI but in most cases you can just pass the list, e.g. `y_range=['Apples', 'Pears', 'Nectarines', 'Plums', 'Grapes', 'Strawberries']` will suffice.